# Laravel - What to write in view to get current prefix {{URL::to('prefix/search')}}

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5, routes

Basically what I wan't to do is to automatically change de prefix so I only have one view. The links could look something like this.

```
{{URL::to('california/search')}}
{{URL::to('florida/search')}}
{{URL::to('arkansas/search')}}
```

I use Laravel 5.2

This is the controllers i use:

```
//Controllers for states
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'california', "namespace" => 'Test' ), function() {    
    Route::get("/all", "CalifornaPositionController@all");
    Route::get('/search',['uses' => 'CalifornaPositionController@getSearch','as' => 'search']);
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'CalifornaPositionController@show');

});
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'florida', "namespace" => 'Test' ), function() {    
    Route::get("/all", "FloridadPositionController@all");
    Route::get('/search',['uses' => 'FloridadPositionController@getSearch','as' => 'search']);
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'FloridadPositionController@show');

});
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'arkansas', "namespace" => 'Test' ), function() {    
    Route::get("/all", "ArkansasPositionController@all");
    Route::get('/search',['uses' => 'ArkansasPositionController@getSearch','as' => 'search']);
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'ArkansasPositionController@show');

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Laravel API docs for [Request](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_route) and [Route](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getPrefix) folowing code retrieves current route prefix

```
Request::route()->getPrefix()
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved the problem.

```
{{URL::to(Request::route()->getPrefix().'/search')}}
```

If this makes more sense.

```
<?php $prefix = Request::route()->getPrefix(); ?>
{{URL::to($prefix.'/search')}}
```