# Getting laravel prefix group value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a prefix route group and I am gonna taking those prefix value to show different header for different route group, so how I get only prefix value and maybe putting some if in my view?

I have route group like this

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'cu'), function(){
    Route::get('login',array('as' => 'cu.login','uses' => 'AdminAuthController@getLogin_public'));
    Route::post('login',array('as' =>'cu.login.post','uses' => 'AdminAuthController@postLogin_public'));
    Route::get('logout',array('as' => 'cu.logout','uses' => 'AdminAuthController@getLogout_public'));
});
```

So how I get `cu` value in my view?
Note: I am still using `laravel 4.2`.

Edit:
As i said before, i'm still using laravel 4.2 and most of solution getprefix won't work in here... so maybe there is another method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - What to write in view to get current prefix {{URL::to('prefix/search')}}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538327/laravel-what-to-write-in-view-to-get-current-prefix-urltoprefix-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try both:

```
$pref = $this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix();
```

And:

```
public function action(Request $request)
{
    $pref = $request->route()->getPrefix();
}
```

Then pass `$pref` to a view and use it. This work for 5+, but not sure about 4.2.

For 4.2 try this:

```
@if (\Request::is('some_prefix/*'))

@endif
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try another solution.

Comment: wow thanks... it works... this is the most simplest solution that i looking for these few days around the internet.... Thank A lot Man!!